# Invoke getter in firefox dev tools only work in watch panel

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools, firefox-developer-edition

In firefox developer 66.0b1 (all extension disabled), "invoke getter" feature doesn't work in debugger panel but work in watch expression panel.

I make a file script.js and include to a index.html in the same folder to test like this:

```
var obj = {
  key1: "hello",
  key2: "world",
  get world() {
    return this.key1 + ' ' + this.key2;
  }
};

console.log(obj);
console.log('done');
```

I set break point at line `console.log('done');` . When i start debugging, i click "invoke getter" (the >> button) in debugger panel but nothing happen.

[image]

It works in watch expression panel:

[image]

Has this feature not been finished yet or Is my firefox install broken?

Comment: I too am experiencing this not working.